# What's this operator in C?

Tags: c

I saw someone use `(b, c)` in C.

I tested it like:

```
printf("%d\n", (0, 0));
printf("%d\n", (0, 1));
printf("%d\n", (1, 0));
printf("%d\n", (1, 1));
```

the result is:

```
0
1
0
1
```

but still dunno why it only output value `c`.

Could someone let me know what the operator is?

Comment: It's the comma operator.  It's typically used in a `for` loop, to perform multiple assignments in one of the sections of the `for` statement.